# How to return status code to handler in Go

Tags: json, go, rest

I have a simple rest API and i need to transfer status code from getAPI function to handler. I suppose that problem is that NewDecoder handle only response body. But how can i solve this problem and transfer not only body, but status code

> here i want to choose, if i have status code 404 it will be one
> response, if i have status 200 code it will be another

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch h.Data["action"].(string) {
    case "catalogue":
    url := "https:...."
    resp.getAPI(url)
        if resp.StatusCode == 404 {
            h.Speech = append(h.Speech, "Call another code.")
        } else {
            h.Speech = []string{resp.Material.Url}
        }
}
```

> here i send request and here i need to transfer res.StatusCode to
> handler

```
func (resp *api) getAPI(url string) {
    
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    res, err := client.Do(req)

    defer res.Body.Close()

    
    err = json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&resp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("decode body", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you probably want to use WriteHeader on ResponseWriter

```
    // WriteHeader sends an HTTP response header with the provided
    // status code.
    //
    // If WriteHeader is not called explicitly, the first call to Write
    // will trigger an implicit WriteHeader(http.StatusOK).
    // Thus explicit calls to WriteHeader are mainly used to
    // send error codes.
    //
    // The provided code must be a valid HTTP 1xx-5xx status code.
    // Only one header may be written. Go does not currently
    // support sending user-defined 1xx informational headers,
    // with the exception of 100-continue response header that the
    // Server sends automatically when the Request.Body is read.
    WriteHeader(statusCode int)
```